# qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators missing in Qt6

Tags: qt5, qt6, qmetatype

I am porting some Qt5 code to Qt6, and one of the functions called is [qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators).

Compiling this code results in:

> 'qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators' was not declared in this scope

I assumed I just needed to include `QMetaType`, but that doesn't work.  And I can't find reference to this function on the Qt website.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove it.
Quoting from [What's New in QMetaType + QVariant](https://www.qt.io/blog/whats-new-in-qmetatype-qvariant)

> Moreover, we considered the registries to be a bit clunky. After all, why should we require you to call QMetaType::registerEqualsComparator() when we could already know this by simply looking at the type? So in Qt 6, QMetaType::registerEqualsComparator, QMetaType::registerComparators, qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators and QMetaType::registerDebugStreamOperator have been removed. **The metatype system will instead know about those automatically**.